# Divisibilty of $1^{101} + 2^{101} + 3^{101}+ 4^{101}+\cdots+2016^{101}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-theorem

$1^{101} + 2^{101} + 3^{101}+ 4^{101}+\cdots+2016^{101}$ is divisible by which of the following?

$(A)$ $2014$

$(B)$ $2015$

$(C)$ $2016$

$(D)$ $2017$

Could someone share the approach to deal with such type of questions?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) $$1^{101}+2016^{101}=(1+2016)A_1=2017A_1$$
$$2^{101}+2015^{101}=(2+2015)A_2=2017A_2$$
...
$$1008^{101}+1009^{101}=(1008+1009)A_{1008}=2017A_{1008}$$

2) $$1^{101}+2015^{101}=(1+2015)B_1=2016B_1$$
$$2^{101}+2014^{101}=(2+2014)B_2=2016B_2$$
...
$$2016^{101}=2016B$$ But $$2016 \not |1013^{101}$$
Similarly, for $2015$ and $2014$

Answer: $2017$

Comment: What's $A_1 {}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: ${A_1}$  some positive integer

Comment: Why $$1^{101}+2016^{101}=(1+2016)A_1=2017A_1$$ How can you take out $A_1$ common?

Comment: Use formula $$a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}=(a+b)(a^{2k}-a^{2k-1}b+...+b^{2k})$$